# Apache Camel: Using split() and resequence() with multithreading

Tags: multithreading, split, apache-camel

I have a question concerning the integration of split(), resequence() together with multithreading. My (naive) routes are looking like this (abbreviated to explain the problem):

```
from("file:input")
    .process(prioAssign)
    .split(body().tokenize("\n")).streaming()
        .resequence().simple("${in.header.prio}").allowDuplicates().reverse()
        .to("direct:process")    
    .end()
    .process(exportProcessor)

from("direct:process")
    .threads(10, 100, "process")
    .process(importProcessor) // take some time for processing
```

I like to accomplish the following things:

1. The importProcessor work should be distributed over several threads
2. The items (coming from the splitter) should be processed by priority (resequenced)
3. The exportProcessor must be triggered when all splitted objects are processed (from one file)

The problem with the code above is, that if I include the resequence step, the export is triggered immediately and the resequencing itself doesn't work. It seems, I don't understand the threading model behind Camel.

Thanks a lot in advance for all hints!

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't it be that your prioAssign processor doesn't build a body that can be split later, and so the split ends instantly and everything moves to the exportProcessor?